# Create new empty file of a given extension and open it from Terminal

Tags: file, shell, cmd, command, file-extension

I have made a python programm that can open files, for example **document.docx**. If the file exists, everything is fine: I open it with the command

- `start document.docx` on Windows
- `xdg-open document.docx` on Linux.

Howewer, **I would now like to create the document if it doesn't exist**, for example create a new empty file called `new.docx` and open it in the default program.

My solution would be to store an empty file of every type I wish to use (an empty docx, an empty odt, an empty png, ...), and if the file that the user asks for doesn't exist, the program makes a copy of the empty file named after the user's input and opens it.

Do you think they might be a solution that would work for both Windows and Ubuntu that wouldn' need to store an empty file for each of the extensions used ?

Edit: I would like to have the same behaviour as what you do when you create a file in the context menu of windows, you can choose a lot of different types of documents

[image: New File]

(It's french but you get it)

Comment: When you do the new->Word Document, it just creates a file called New Microsoft Word Document.docx with no bytes in the file. Word handles opening this file gracefully, but if you edit it and save it, it will write all the usually crazy Word formatting.

Comment: And do you think that opening a file with no bytes would work with other extensions ?

Comment: It would be completely dependent on the application. It certainly isn't valid for png. Windows Picture Viewer would just show "Cannot display this file because it is empty." But what *is* a new png anyway? That seems correct to me.

Comment: So the solution of storing an empty new file for each needed extension is probably the most reliable ?

Comment: Oh, your original solution right? I mean, that seems like it would definitely work. I don't know if it is the most elegant solution (I don't know that it isn't either).

Comment: Yep my original solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34386/discussion-between-edi9999-and-gray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original solution (of using templates for all needed file types) seems to be the standard way of doing things as that is how both Windows and Ubuntu (Nautilus) do things.

Windows uses the Registry and Windows\ShellNew to access existing templates. [source](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu)

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx\ShellNew]
"FileName"="New Microsoft Word Document.docx"
```

> With a file with that name in `%windir%\ShellNew`.

As does Ubuntu (Nautilus) but with the ~/Templates/ directory. [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208291/how-to-create-a-new-blank-file-in-nautilus-3-6)

So it seems like your most robust solution is just to stick with what you were doing originally.